# Rendering - Noise issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, denoise

This is my first post in Blender. I'm currently working on this sugarcane's project, But The rendering result cause a lot of noise or flicking issues. can any one give me a advise? I got turn on Denoising and 120 Samples. much appreciated if you guys could give me a hand. thanks 
[image]

Below is the test rendering link. please have a look.
https://youtu.be/j08kpjA4r4A

Comment: Perhaps it would help to include a shot of your render settings, too....

Comment: You need more samples. Try 250 or 500

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried 500 samples. I will also check it out the link you sent. thanks.